# Select second highest value per distinct foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

So, I have two tables, account and invoice, they are linked by the primary key from the account table ie. account.key and invoice.key.

I want to select account.accountnumber, invoice.invoicedate, invoice.invoiceamount for the second latest invoicedate from each account.

Any ideas?

So to select all invoices and their corresponding account numbers:

```
select a.accountnumber, i.invoicedate, i.invoiceamount
from account a
join invoice i on (a.key = i.key)
```

And to select the second latest invoice from the entire invoice table:

```
select MAX(invoicedate) from INVOICE i where invoicedate NOT IN (SELECT MAX(invoicedate) from i
```

But how do I get the second latest invoice, per account from the invoice table, along with the account number from the account table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) windowing function...

```
select accountnumber, invoicedate, invoiceamount 
from 
(
    select a.accountnumber, i.invoicedate, i.invoiceamount, 
        row_number() over (partition by a.accountnumber order by invoicedate desc) rn
    from account a 
        join invoice i on a.[key] = i.[key]
) v
where rn = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

try using this:

```
select a.accountnumber, i.invoicedate, i.invoiceamount 
from account a 
join invoice i on a.[key] = i.[key]
and i.invoicedate in
(select max(invoicedate) as secondmaxdate from invoice where invoicedate not in
(select max(invoicedate) as maxdate from invoice group by [key])
group by [key])
```

Comment: Not only is this over convoluted, it won't work if invoices share dates.